# What is the easiest way to generate a pi diagram or bar diagram from raw data?

Tags: software-rec, statistics

#### Background:

I want to see an statistics on my spent time in several categories like sports, study, movie etc. throughout a certain period of time.

To visualize it, I have to represent it in pi diagram and bar diagram.

Pi diagram would be simply percentage of spent times in every category.

Bar diagram would show Category vs spent time scenario.

I can write a program in java to collect the raw data in a text file or in  a database in any string format.

#### Need:

Is there any existing software that would take the raw data from file or database in a specific format and would draw the pi diagram and bar diagram?

#### Study:

I know there already exists such type of software, but they are paid. I did not found any full free software, but some freemium software.

#### Input System:

The JAVA software which I told to write would take input in two form.

1. I can press <kbd>Start</kbd> button and a counter would be started and later I would press <kbd>Stop</kbd> button when the work would be finished. The software would calculate the duration and add to the raw data.
2. I also can manually Input my work details from when to when I worked for an specific category. Software would take the data and add to raw data.

#### Note:

I am using Windows 10 OS.

I am not fully familiar with questions in this site. But I thought this question best fits in this site. So, I am asking it here. If you think the question is more appropriate in any other site, then don't hesitate to have a migration request.

Comment: What wrong with using a spreadsheet to do this? That's what they are for. OpenOffice and LibreOffice are free.

Comment: How to do it in spreadsheet taking input from text file or from database? Can it be that easy to see the statistics dynamically changing the range? @DavidPostill

Comment: [Connect a SQL Server database to your workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad)

Comment: [Connect external data to your workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-external-data-to-your-workbook-945f2cbb-d50b-4ee2-bae8-c4c9381000c6)

Comment: Is it possible to connect with mySQL database? I worked only in mySQL and Oracle database.

Comment: Please start to do your own research - I've given you some suggestions to think about. We are not here to give you complete solutions.

Comment: For openoffice [Connect MySQL and Base](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base)

Comment: If you can write Java then you can learn VBA. Leave the graphing to programs designed for that - spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for your cordial help. I would start working. @DavidPostill

Comment: No problem. For future questions, please note that we expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: However, can you give me some resources to cover VBA early? @DavidPostill

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29931/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-manetsus).